# how to show result of method in graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have tried to create a data analysis report with `matplotlib`. In it, multiple plotting will be. Design is

```
|--------------------------------------------------------|
||--------------| |-------------------------------------||
||              | |                                     ||
||    Title     | |                                     ||
|| author name  | |          histograms                 ||
||              | |                                     ||
||              | |                                     ||
||--------------| |                                     ||
||--------------| |                                     ||
||              | |                                     ||
||  summary     | |                                     ||
||              | |                                     ||
||--------------| |-------------------------------------||
|--------------------------------------------------------|
```

In summary part, I want to display `pandas.DataFrame.describe()`. How can I do that?

Above the summary, I want to display title with my name and date. How can I do that?

I know to `import matplotlib.pyplot as mat` and know how to use `mat.subplot2grid()` to put a specific plot in the specified area. But, I don't get how to put result of a function in an area and create own title with description in an another area like shown below:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
||---------------------------------| |-------------------------------------||
||                                 | |                                     ||
|| Summary table for Capgemini     | |                                     ||
|| by Caren Van Der Lee            | |          histograms                 ||
||                                 | |                                     ||
||                                 | |                                     ||
||---------------------------------| |                                     ||
||---------------------------------| |                                     ||
||                                 | |                                     ||
||       summary  by               | |                                     ||
||  pandas.DataFrame.describe()    | |                                     ||
||---------------------------------| |-------------------------------------||
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: Why downvote?  The reason?

Comment: The reason for the downvote is likely that you haven't given any examples of what you have tried. Coming on here and saying "How do I do this?" without even providing any code of what you have tried, generally isn't met well.

Comment: Adding text: http://matplotlib.org/users/text_intro.html

Comment: @caren vanderlee Can you specify what the result of the function is?

Comment: @carenvanderlee insulting other users also isn't likely to help.  Saying that you know how to do something isn't as helpful as showing the code you've used so far.

Comment: Please take some time to read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Based off the link that Amy Teegarden posted, you'll pass the coordinates and a string to the `.figtext()` method to add text.

> I don't get how to put result of a function in an area and create own title with description in an another area like shown below:

I don't know what the result of the function is, but if you can convert that to a string you can output it with `.figtext()`.

As per the example that Amy Teegarden linked:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('bold figure suptitle', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
ax.set_title('Title goes here')
result = function(param1, param2, ...)
ax.figtext(3, 8, result)
```

You can specify more customizations for the `.figtext()` by overloading the method such as coloring and bold/italicization.

I haven't coded in python in a while so this may be a shot in the dark.

---

**Edit:**

pandas.DataFrame.describe() returns an [NDFrame object](http://nullege.com/codes/search/pandas.core.generic.NDFrame) which can be accessed as an array(multidimensional based on the specific type). [Here is a link](http://matplotlib.org/examples/index.html) that shows examples of adding different objects to matplotlib if you decide to format it differently.